# sympy simplify cannot recognize square of a binomial

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I have several expression where simplification would drastically improve if simplify would be able to recognize the square of a binomial just as in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to let sympy/simplify do this?

```
import sympy as sp
a, b = sp.symbols('a, b', positive=True)
sp.simplify(sp.sqrt(a**2))
test = a + b - sp.sqrt(a**2+b**2+2*a*b)
sp.simplify(test)
```

Comment: It is good to post the code instead of images

Comment: You can use `factor(test, deep=True)`.

Comment: thanks @Oscar Benjamin this does the job!

Answer (score 0):

> --- this is 0, but sympy/simplify cannot recognise square of binomial

No it is not, the problem is not with sympy but with your understanding of the math.

`a + b - sqrt(a\*\*2 + b\*\*2 + 2\*a\*b)` is not equal to `0`, it is equal to `(a + b) +- (a + b)` or in other words; it is equal to either `0` OR `2 * (a + b)`, this is because `sqrt((a + b)**2)` is equal to `+- (a + b)`.

`+-` used here to mean "plus or minus".

Comment: See the docs for [`sqrt`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sqrt): it returns the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value), which in the case of positive inputs will be the positive root.

Comment: i think you missed the fact that a and b are assumed to be positive